# Is there a simple method to produce a histogram of the Wilson distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, histogram

The Wilson score for some observed binomial distribution $(\hat{p},N)$ gives you a confidence interval on $p$.

However, I need a histogram over the possible values of $p$. (With a relatively low number of evenly spaced bins)

I looked at [1] https://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/staff/sean/resources/wilson-distribution.pdf (Sean Wallis) where they compute a distribution plot based on knowing the Wilson score at varying confidence levels.

Unfortunately this leads to quite complicated code, and makes it difficult to get a good approximation of all bins in the histogram.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Too much like "Please check my code". There is statistical flavour here, but it's mostly about whether your code is correct, which is in my view off-topic here.

Comment: I see your point. I tried changing the question to not involve my own (possibly wrong) solution

Comment: Sorry, but even if the question is now on-topic I can't follow what kind of answer you're seeking.  The bad news, which will be disappointing but should not be surprising, is that to get anywhere a question here has to be on-topic and answerable. Also, the question seems to depend on people reading a lengthy document. References are fine here, but the ideal is that questions should be self-contained.

Comment: maybe a way to express it, is to come up with a cdf() for the wilson distribution...